# How to update graphics card driver in ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: 12.04, graphics, eeepc

I have an Asus eee r101 pc,and wonder if anyone knows how to update the graphics drive in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: it is helpful http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/resources/how-to-update-driver-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 6):

Go to '**System Settings**' and under '**Hardware**' section click on '**Additional Drivers**'. It will automatically search for drivers and it will ask if you want to install the graphics drivers.

In **short**

**System Settings** -> '**Hardware**' section -> **Additional Drivers**

PS:

You can search for **System Settings** in **unity dash**.

Just hit **Super Key**(that key which has windows logo between left Ctrl and left Alt on the bottom left of keyboard) and type **System Settings** and hit [ENTER] to open it.

Comment: I don't have "Additional Drivers" in my Hardware section. Could it be hidden? (12.04 LTS)

Comment: Try going to `Software and Updates`. It should be the last tab in the pop up.

Comment: How can you get to System Settings on GUI without having a clean GUI. Isn't there a console application ?

Answer (score 5):

Follow these instruction it is helpful

- go to **System Setting**
- then **Softwares and Updates**
- then **additional drivers**
- then here you will find **all list of drivers**

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the stable *PPA*, if you want to stay updated with your drivers:

1. Open a terminal and enter this command:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
   ```
2. Reboot your system and you're done

Comment: What if you have AMD or Intel?